# class java.awt.Font error - Android

Tags: android

When I try to edit project/res/main.xml using android layout editor in eclipse I
get the error "Could not initialize class java.awt.font".

I don't know, how to get rid of this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just installed jre, so the java.awt was not found.
You should install jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse must be using a JDK that is not from sun.
Try the following.

Update /etc/eclipse.ini with

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/bin/
```

Replace the jvm path with where your sun jvm is installed.
Add this line just after a line that looks like below

```
256m
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ubuntu?

Because I do and I got same problem, but I tried to install openjdk-6-jre from the repository and this problem is solved.

Hope this work for you